Disposition of $m, n$ colored balls.
Let $m$, $n$ be numbers of red and white balls, respectively. Suppose that we are to distribute these balls into $l$ boxes, which we don't distinguish. That is, boxes are unlabelled. Then
Q. Is there a general formula of different distributions of these balls?
For example, suppose that $m = 2, n = 2, l = 2$. Then there are following $5$ different cases:
(red 0, white 0) (red 2, white 2)
(red 0, white 1) (red 2, white 1)
(red 0, white 2) (red 2, white 0)
(red 1, white 0) (red 1, white 2)
(red 1, white 1) (red 1, white 1)

In the above, two boxes with each $1$ red ball are NOT distinguished. If we distinguish boxes the formula will be obtained from the simple combinatrical viewpoint. I have difficulty in finding solutions in this problem.

It is important here to note that unlabeled boxes can become labeled if numbers or compositions differ
In the example you have given, of the $5$ cases, only the last case can be treated as unlabeled because they are identical both in number and composition
The number of possibilities (written in full without omitting obvious computations) will thus be
$\binom20\binom20\binom22\binom22 
 +\binom20\binom21\binom22\binom11  
+ \binom20\binom22 \binom22\binom00  
+ \binom21\binom20\binom11\binom22  
+ \binom21\binom21\binom11\binom11 /2!$
[Note the division by 2! for the last case, unlabeled due to identical contents]
It is akin to forming labeled/unlabeled teams with which you must be familiar, you could see here for further clarity
Added
There can't be a general formula for $m,n,l$, because it will depend upon how the balls are divided. The general approach is to distribute the components box by box in the usual manner, and in case $k_1, k_2...$ boxes have identical contents, divide by $k_1!, k_2!...$ for those boxes

Great thank. In short there cannot be any simple formula to the general l, m, n. I wonder if the induction approach will help.
